# Kernel downgrade after update broke my system

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I need to downgrade from 3.8.0-33 to version -29. After booting the latest kernel I'm greeted by a black screen. How do I keep this version permanently?

Output of `dpkg -l linux-image*`

```
Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
| Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
         Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
|/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht)
||/ Name           Version        Beschreibung
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  linux-image    <keine>        (keine Beschreibung vorhanden)
un  linux-image-3. <keine>        (keine Beschreibung vorhanden)
ii  linux-image-3. 3.8.0-29.42~pr Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-3. 3.8.0-33.48~pr Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 b
ii  linux-image-ge 3.8.0.33.33    Generic Linux kernel image
```

Sorry it's German.

Comment: Can you instead use `dpkg -l linux-image* | cat`? It cannot be seen the proper kernel versions. Also the output of `apt-cache linux-image-3.8*`

Comment: Shoot in the dark; The kernel jump from 3.8.0-29 to 33 had some fixes\changes to backlight that might didn't turn out well for all. You can try [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) from ubuntu wiki. Some have also reported success with adding the kernel boot parameter `acpi_osi=Linux` If it worked can the change can be done more permanent in grub config. Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove the non-functional kernel with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic
```

As part of uninstallation process the system removes `3.8.0-33` entry from GRUB menu and leaves only `3.8.0-29`.

Please note, that also package `linux-image-generic-lts-raring` will be removed. That means that your kernel version will not be upgraded in future with `apt-get upgrade`. Only when you reinstall `linux-image-generic-lts-raring` will the kernel version get upgraded. So this is a permanent solution.

Comment: How do you reinstall `linux-image-generic-lts-raring`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you still have installed your old kernel, but your default entry in Grub is the new kernel. If that is the case, boot into your old kernel and try running this:

```
sudo /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
```

This should update your Grub menu with your desired kernel version. Note that the default entry will be replaced again with new updates.