# 12.04 LTS: Kernel Update to 3.13.0-44 broke my-weather-indicator

Tags: 12.04, kernel, my-weather-indicator

After doing the kernel update today, my-weather-indicator disappeared from the indicator bar on my 12.04LTS boxes.  If I try to start it manually, the icon flashes in the launcher for a couple of seconds and vanishes.

Even after doing the kernel update to 3.16.0-29 on a 14.10 box, my-weather-indicator is OK there, though.

Any suggestions on how to recover my-weather-indicator for 12.04LTS?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me few days ago on 14.04 with the kernel update to 3.13.0-46. After I've found your quetion today I tried to install utopic kernel backport and it works again! You can install it too with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

If you don't want to upgrade to utopic kernel for some reason, you can boot into the last working kernel (at grub pick advanced options for ubuntu and then choose the kernel you want) and then purge the newer kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic
```

see this topic for more info on that:
[Kernel downgrade after update broke my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375844/kernel-downgrade-after-update-broke-my-system)