# Roll back kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I recently upgraded my kernel version to 3.19.3 and most of the stuff is not working (eg. Wireless, installing b43 doesn't help too, fglrx etc.) which seemed to work beautifully before , how can I rollback my kernel version avoiding the `make` and `make module_install install` which takes hours to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot up the machine, and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left Shift key (if a boot loader does not show up by itself). Then select 'advanced options for Ubuntu' and select the working kernel and press enter.

---

Then you can edit grub itself and make that kernel as default.
If you are not 100% comfortable editing the configuration file `/etc/default/grub`, you can use [grub-customizer](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer &> /dev/null &  # to start it in the background
```

Go to the tab General Settings and select from 'default entry' whichever kernel version is your preferred default (see snapshot). You may also move working the kernel entries up and down in the List Configuration tab if you want, but that's mainly presentational.

[image: Sceenshot from Grub Configuration 5.0.6]

---

Or do

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

else you can select exact kernel version that is not need and remove and then run grub update [Kernel downgrade after update broke my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375844/kernel-downgrade-after-update-broke-my-system)

Comment: I recommend power users to use the grub-customizer still. In my computer there are two `grub.cfg` files under `/boot/grub/` and `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. In the first it is explicitly suggested NOT TO EDIT THIS FILE. It can be easily become a minefield for the less expert