# 14.04 update: kernel crypto interface not available

Tags: 14.04, kernel

A few days ago, after a sytem update to kernel 3.19.0-56, I can not open anymore a tcrypt volume with cryptsetup. I get the following error:

```
sudo cryptsetup open --type tcrypt /dev/sda tcryptDisk
Enter passphrase: 
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Ensure you have algif_skcipher kernel module loaded.
```

Trying to load the mentioned module does not resolve the issue:

```
sudo modprobe algif_skcipher
```

Any pointer greatly appreciated!

Seb

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue after a kernel update to ***3.13.0-83-generic***.  It appears to be bug with that kernel version reported on 3/16/16:

[cryptsetup tcryptOpen doesn't work anymore](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1558079)

My temporary fix was to [revert back to the previously installed kernel version](https://askubuntu.com/a/377357/6562).

Confirm current version:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-83-generic
```

Remove 3.13.0-83 version:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic
```

Reboot your machine and confirm version:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-79-generic
```

Kernel 3.13.0-79-generic works for me and no longer get any error messages with `cryptsetup`.

Since you appear to be on a much newer version 3.19.0-56 you may need to somehow get to 3.19.0-51 which one of the commentators in the bug indicates it was still working "fine".

Instead of downgrading, you may try [booting into that specific version via grub and setting it as your default](https://askubuntu.com/a/610335/6562).