# No sound after installing update 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Running 14.04 on an Intel NUC with HDMI output to home theater (no built in speakers).  Previous to most recent update everything was fine.  Now I get no sound.  I followed the advice on all the related posts I could find - and there are many - but nothing has worked so far.

I'm strictly copy and paste ubuntu user - any help greatly appreciated.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: ID 2807 Digital [ID 2807 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks much,

cpaul

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same symptoms after a recent apt-get dist-upgrade in 14.04, which updated the kernel. Tried also the old tricks, nothing worked. The only error I could find in any logs was in dmesg about a missing symbol (intel 915 something or other) needed by the hda driver. Reverting kernel back from 3.13.0-65 to 3.13.0-63 solved it for me.

Don't know if the cause of your symptoms is the same as mine. However, if you want to try, here's how.

To try whether this helps in your case, without doing any permanent changes, try booting with an older kernel and see if sound over HDMI works. To do this, see [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time). I couldn't get to the grub menu by pressing shift, instead I had to modify /etc/default/grub (and run sudo update-grub) as described in the other post.

Use the instructions from the other link, when you get to the grub boot menu, the older kernels are in a sub-menu, I think it was called something like "Advanced Ubuntu options". From the sub-menu pick a kernel older than 3.13.0-65. For me, everything older than that worked. I also tried 3.13.0-66 - did not work for me.

Once I found out that an older kernel works, I permanently reverted back to that version. See [Kernel downgrade after update broke my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375844/kernel-downgrade-after-update-broke-my-system) for instructions how to do that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's how all the cool kids do it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry